# Getting NumberFormatException for Spring Boot rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on the following API in Spring Boot:

```
/fetchStudents?prefix=<prefix>&fetchSize=<fetchSize>
```

I am implementing the rest API as follows:

```
  @GetMapping("/fetchStudents")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Student> getStudents(@RequestParam String prefix,
                                                   @RequestParam(defaultValue="50") int fetchSize) {
   ....
  }
```

While calling the API as: `/fetchStudents?prefix='a'&fetchSize=50`, I am getting `NumberFormatException`. I am not getting how to fix this issue.

Comment: if you put a number for example `2` for `prefix`, do you get the exception again?

Comment: Can you update the question with full stacktrace of execption ?

Comment: Provide a name field in the requestParam to let your API identify which parameter is provided `@RequestParam(defaultValue = "A" ,required = false,name = "prefix") String prefix` try this

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from the `a` param that is surrounded by ` signs.

Since you send it in the URL it should be encoded to `%60a%60`

So it seems like Spring is not reading the first param correctly and that effects the second param of `fetchSize`

Try to eliminate parts of the query params to better identify the problem:

- `/fetchStudents?fetchSize=50`
- `/fetchStudents?fetchSize=50&prefix='a'`
- `/fetchStudents?fetchSize=50&prefix=%60a%60`

Comment: So @riorio there is no way where I can put prefix before fetchsize ?

Comment: @Joy try sending it without the ` signs or with the encoding of %60. Once you fix that, the order of the params should not be relevant.

Comment: Actually @riorio I am calling the API from swagger, so I don't have any control regarding how the API is invoked. Any suggestions how to handle this in service ?

Comment: @Joy can you simply send `a` without the ` signs?

Comment: I am not passing `a` with any sign.

Comment: @Joy He mean `'` (single quote)